# Existing png image not opened by opencv

Tags: python, image, opencv, nonetype, imread

I am currently encountering a very strange problem that I couldn't find an explanation for. I have a text file containg a list of filenames. The idea is to read this text file and read the corresponding images one by one thanks to imread. But something very strange happens, as when I try to open the image by manually inputing the first path of the list, it works, but when I do it reading the list file, it doesn't work. It will be clearer with the test I ran :

```py
entepath='INRIAPerson'
line = 'Train/pos/crop_000010.png'

plt.figure()
img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, line), cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
plt.imshow(img)
with open(os.path.join(path, 'Train', 'pos.lst'), 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line)
        plt.figure()
        img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, line), cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
        plt.imshow(img)
        break
```

The output is this:

```py
    Train/pos/crop_000010.png

    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-24-6de28785d7e8> in <module>
          9         plt.figure()
         10         img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, line), cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    ---> 11         plt.imshow(img)
         12         break

    ~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py in imshow(X, cmap, norm, aspect, interpolation, alpha, vmin, vmax, origin, extent, shape, filternorm, filterrad, imlim, resample, url, data, **kwargs)
       2699         filternorm=filternorm, filterrad=filterrad, imlim=imlim,
       2700         resample=resample, url=url, **({"data": data} if data is not
    -> 2701         None else {}), **kwargs)
       2702     sci(__ret)
       2703     return __ret

    ~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py in inner(ax, data, *args, **kwargs)
       1808                         "the Matplotlib list!)" % (label_namer, func.__name__),
       1809                         RuntimeWarning, stacklevel=2)
    -> 1810             return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
       1811 
       1812         inner.__doc__ = _add_data_doc(inner.__doc__,

    ~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py in imshow(self, X, cmap, norm, aspect, interpolation, alpha, vmin, vmax, origin, extent, shape, filternorm, filterrad, imlim, resample, url, **kwargs)
       5492                               resample=resample, **kwargs)
       5493 
    -> 5494         im.set_data(X)
       5495         im.set_alpha(alpha)
       5496         if im.get_clip_path() is None:

    ~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py in set_data(self, A)
        640         if (self._A.dtype != np.uint8 and
        641                 not np.can_cast(self._A.dtype, float, "same_kind")):
    --> 642             raise TypeError("Image data cannot be converted to float")
        643 
        644         if not (self._A.ndim == 2

    TypeError: Image data cannot be converted to float
```

It is important to note that the first image gets plotted (and therefore has been loaded) while the second doesn't. I have no idea why it doesn't work in the second case, might it be a problem with multiple files openings ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you print the result of `os.path.join(path, line)` within the for loop? Also you have a local and global variable named `line`. Could you use unique names instead to improve code readability

Comment: The result is `INRIAPerson/Train/pos/crop000010.png`, I already did the test, everything matches. For the variable naming, indeed, I only created the global one for testing therefore didn't bother with readibility, my bad. But problem holds unfortunately :(

Comment: Are you able to plot the shape of the image? `img.shape()`. The error appears to be coming from matplotlib. Wondering if the package is somehow corrupt, which may be why it's throwing an error.

Comment: No, the image is `None` within the loop, `img.shape` throws a similar error.

Comment: As a sanity check, can you run a string comparison in python between `os.path.join(path, line)` and the actual path of the image. Also, try using `img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, line))` to read the image instead of using `cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED`

Comment: It yields `True` and I have indeed done the test with `cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED`, result is the same. I am quite perplex.